# How to override event (dropEvent) of a widget in dynamic UI of PyQt?

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyqt4

**What am I doing/ What I have so far :**

I am using Qt-designer to create PyQt .ui file which I am loading in my python script using QUiLoader which gives me access to the widgets/components as :

```
self.ui.tree_widget_of_items ( which is a QTreeWidget created in Qt-designer)
```

I am able to read and write the values of widgets and I am able to use the signal on TreeWidget like this :

```
self.ui.tree_widget_of_items.itemSelectionChanged.connect(self.myFunction)
```

**What I am trying to do ?**

- I want to override dropEvent of treeWidget in my python script

**What I have tried but didn't work :**

```
self.ui.tree_widget_of_items.dropEvent = self.drop_action

def drop_action(self,e):
    print "drop action"
```

I have tried assigning a my own function to dropEvent of TreeWidget but it doesn't get triggered when I drop an item on TreeWidget.

I have also tried :

```
self.ui.tree_widget_of_items.dragEnterEvent = self.drop_action
```

I made sure that Drag and Drop is enabled on TreeWidget.

Answer (score 4):

To implement Events in dynamic UI (which means UI created in Qt-designer and used in python tool using .ui file). You need following things :

1. MainWindow class of your tool should inherit QtGui.QMainWindow

   ```
   class main_window(QtGui.QMainWindow):
   ```
2. It should call super().**init**()

   ```
   class main_window(QtGui.QMainWindow):
       def __init__(self, parent=None):
           super(main_window, self).__init__(parent)

           loader = QUiLoader()
           file = QtCore.QFile(os.path.join(SCRIPT_DIRECTORY, 'mainwindow.ui'))
           file.open(QtCore.QFile.ReadOnly)
           if parent:
               self.ui = loader.load(file, parentWidget=parent)
           else:
               self.ui = loader.load(file)
           file.close()
   ```
3. Install EventFilter on component :

   ```
   self.ui.tree_widget_of_items.installEventFilter(self)      
   # not --> self.ui.tree_widget_of_items.installEventFilter(self.ui)
   ```
4. Define eventFilter() :

   ```
   def eventFilter(self, o, e):
   if (o.objectName() == "tree_widget_of_items"):
       if e.type() == QtCore.QEvent.Type.Enter:
           self.drop_action(e)
   ```

Answer (score 2):

You have to install an event filter on the tree and implement the `QObject.eventFilter` method in your class.

Example (install event filter):

```
self.ui.tree_widget_of_items.installEventFilter(self)
```

And implement eventFilter:

```
def eventFilter(self, o, e):
    if e.type() == QEvent.DragEnter: #remember to accept the enter event
        e.acceptProposedAction()
        return True
    if e.type() == QEvent.Drop:
        # handle the event
        # ...
        return True
    return False #remember to return false for other event types
```

See [QObject.installEventFilter](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qobject.html#installEventFilter) and [QObject.eventFilter](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qobject.html#eventFilter)